# Magento Update Messages Are Not Appearing

Tags: php, magento

When in the backend (or frontend for that matter) Magento is not showing any update messages.  For example if you were to save a product on submission and redirect to the page you would receive a notice saying that the product was saved.  Everything is working fine except for the notifications being displayed.  I haven't come across this before and haven't a clue where to begin looking.

I'm expecting that it will be something to do with this call...

```
<div id="messages"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

There is now nothing displayed in here at any area of the site.

Cheers for the help in advance!

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Comment: Was it working before? What changed?

Comment: This is a project that was thrown in my lap halfway completed...  It's well too far into junky spagehetti code to unravel it all and start a new some I'm just trying to patch it up.  So as far as it working before no not since it was passed to me.

Comment: Have had a look in both theme and adminhtml layout files and both seem to have the core/messages block in the appropriate spots

Answer (score 0):

Tried checking the source if the -block is there but empty?

Another idea would be to check the logs (/var/log/exceptions.log).

Comment: The block is showing up but it is empty...
     <div id="messages"></div>
There is nothing in the exceptions.log

Comment: And logging is turned on in Admin?

Comment: You could try loggin from there to see if the function gets called. Something like: Mage::log('getGroupedHtml() called.', null, 'travelingadman.log');

Comment: From log: 2014-02-11T01:16:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): getGroupedHtml() called.

So it is being called...